# Can't remove a folder

Tags: 13.10, directory

This folder had the ubuntu 13.10 iso file. Now when I try to remove it I get an error message with the detail: "Error removing file: No such file or directory"

When I try to open the folder normally through the files explorer it opens another new window that is the same as the one I'm trying to open the folder from.

This happened after I tried to create a live usb using ubuntu (13.10) startup disk creator. It couldn't complete making the usb and gave errors.

I also tried a terminal command with sudo and here's what happened

`rmdir: failed to remove ‘/media/.../.../... (the directory)’: Directory not empty`

Comment: The `rmdir` command is for removing **empty** directories. To quote `man rmdir` : `rmdir - remove empty directories` ;-). Radu's answer *should* work...

Comment: ...oh what shame, I removed it through windows

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command in terminal:

```
rm -rf /path/to/folder
```

See `man rm` for more info.

Comment: `:~$ rm -rf "/path/to/folder"`
`rm: cannot remove ‘/path/to/folder/ubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386.iso’: Is a directory` ???

Comment: wait a second, I think this is because there's a directory inside a directory right?

Comment: anyways I tried modifying the directory to point at the one inside. It gives no errors but the directory inside is still there.

Comment: also tried `sudo rm -r -f`, no errors but directory is still there