# The file or folder /home/XXX/... does not exist. and cannot be deleted

Tags: command-line, directory, duplicate-files

I have a small problem with Kubuntu. I cannot detele some folders and files, it always says to me, the file or folder /src/ doesn't exist?
and now I need to delete them, but i don't know how. someone may help me please. 
Regards

Comment: See here http://askubuntu.com/questions/385073/cant-remove-a-folder

Comment: My guess is that this is a problem of relative vs absolute path. /home/user/src is not the same location as /src (or src for the matter) , and /home/XXX is not the same as /home/user/XXX

Comment: do you want to delete a folder inside home or what ?? elaborate it a little more..

Comment: Please show us your command. On top of that can you post the results of two commands:
`pwd`and 
`ls`

Answer (score 1):

to remove the folder use -

```
sudo rm -f /path/to/the/folder
```

to remove the folders inside it recursively use-

```
sudo rm -r -f /path/to/the/folder
```

here -r stands for recursive and -f stands for force , please make sure to write exact path and exact name of folder.

hope thats what you want.

Comment: Well, OP is asking about a directory in "/home/XXX" and "/src/" so ... /home/src != src != /src. My guess is the problem is with relative vs absolute path.